# How to use ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter in API 12.0?

Tags: android-viewpager, android

I am writing an app for tablet API 3.0. How can I include ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter in my project? Does I must to use compatibility package or this functionality is included in API 3.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, You need to add add android compatible library of v4 in your application or you can also use [actionbarsherlok](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library